# Access a variable from within a method when being passed a block that contains the variable

Tags: ruby, variables, yield, performance-monitor

From what I understand every time it runs though run_times it pops off one of the run_times values and adds it to fake_time. And with my measure method I'm supposed to gather those and get the average. But I can't seem to get the values from within the method.

It needs to pass the following rspec:

```
it "returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times" do
  run_times = [8,6,5,7]
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  average_time = measure(4) do
    fake_time += run_times.pop
end
  average_time.should == 6.5
end
```

*Here's my code:*

```
def measure (n = 1)
  if n > 1 
    n.times { yield }

  else
    start = Time.now
    yield
    elapsed_time = Time.now - start
    elapsed_time

  end

end
```

Thank you in advance! I've been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to get anything working.

Answer (score 0):

`n.times` returns `n`, does not it? that is, `measure` returns `4` if `n` is `4`, so `average_time` is `4`, not `6.5`.

Comment: If this is an answer, it needs a better explanation.

Comment: it does return 4 but i need it to return 6.5. That's the average of the array values. Which I can't seem to access or return.